# Помогите установить javascript на сайт

Tags: javascript, jquery

В разработке сайта, начинающий. Не могу подцепить javascript к шаблону сайта. Выгрузила в Codepen:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#single_1").fancybox({
          helpers: {
              title : {
                  type : 'float'
              }
          }
      });

    $("#single_2").fancybox({
     openEffect : 'elastic',
     closeEffect : 'elastic',

     helpers : {
      title : {
       type : 'inside'
      }
     }
    });

    $("#single_3").fancybox({
     openEffect : 'none',
     closeEffect : 'none',
     helpers : {
      title : {
       type : 'outside'
      }
     }
    });

    $("#single_4").fancybox({
     helpers : {
      title : {
       type : 'over'
      }
     }
    });
});
```

```css
/*Body*/
.body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    
}
*, *::before, *::after{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.container {
    max-width: 1280px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
}

/*Header*/
.header {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.header_iner {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0092db;
    
    padding: 35px 0;  
}
.header_logo{
    float:left;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.logo_company{
    width: 248px;
}

.nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 40px 30px;
    left: 100%;
}

.nav_link{
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 50px;
    color: #175a88;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Roboto; 
    transition: 0.1s linear;     
}

.nav_link:first-child{
    margin-left: 0;
}
.nav_link:hover{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #0092db;
}
.tel_h{
    float: right;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.phone_header{
    display: inline-grid;
}
.phone {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 700;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    float: right;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    text-align: right;
}
.phone_link{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #175a88;
    
    transition: .01s linear;
    margin-top: 4px;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.phone_link:hover{
    color: #0092db;
    text-decoration: none;
} 
.img_phone{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 0 6px 6px 0;
}

.time {
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 2px;
    font-weight: 500;
    color:#175a88;
}
.email {
    color: #175a88;
    font-size: 13px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-top: 3px;
}
    
.email:hover{
    color: #0092db;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.email_link:hover{
    color: #0092db;
    text-decoration: none;   
}
.img_email{
    width: 25px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 5px 15px 0 0;
}
.img_time{
    width: 21px;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 6px 0 2px;   
}
    
.txt_help{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #012350;
    line-height: 1;
}

/*KOMPANI*/

.kompani{
    margin-bottom: 45px;
}
.number{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    justify-content: center;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.numbers_tree{
    margin-right: 85px;
}
.number_kompani {
    font-size: 60px;
    color: #12486d;
    font-weight: bold;
    line-height: 25px;
    margin-top: 30px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-bottom: -2px;
}
.number_img{
    width: 26%;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
.text_kompani{
    font-size: 17px;
    color: #12486d;
    margin-top: 16px;
    margin-left: 9px;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
}
.txt_komp{
    margin-top: 18px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.imaginari{
    width: 380px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 25px;
}
.txt_komp_txt{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    padding-right: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.txt_komp_text{
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #000;
    line-height: 1.5;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: -1px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.certificat{
    margin-top: 40px;
}
.img_for_certificates{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.img_certifi{
    width: 30%;
    margin-top: 15%;
    height: 160px;
}
.img_certifi1{
    width: 70%;
    margin-top: 35%;
    height: 98px;
}

.img_for_product{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.img_pro{
    width: 100%;
    
}
.img_product{
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.phone_txt_inner_text{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
}

/*footer*/

.footer{
    width: 100%;
    background: #12486d;
    padding: 50px 0;
    position: relative;
}
.footer_contact{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    padding: 0 60px;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}
.footer_logo{
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
.logo_img{
    vertical-align: middle;
    border-style: none;
    width: 130%;
    text-align: center;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
.phone_icons{
    text-align: left;
    display: flex;
    width: 22%;
    padding-left: 40px;
}
.phone_txt_inner_text_one{
    text-align: right;
    color: #fff;
    margin-top: -1px;
    font-size: 14px;
    width: 130%;
}
.geo{
    width: 40px;
    height: 25px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
.phone_txt{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.phone_txt_inner_text{
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: normal;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xml:lang="ru" lang="ru">
<head>
    
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
 <meta name="keywords" content="Автоматизация КНС, автоматизация насосных станций"/>
    <meta name="description" content="Автоматизация КНС и насосных станций ООО ИТЦ УКАВТ"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 
<title>Автоматизация КНС и насосных станций ООО "ИТЦ УКАВТ"</title>

    <link rel="icon" href="/images/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/images/favicon1.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href=".../docs/fonts/Roboto/Roboto.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
    
  </head>
<body>
        
<header class="header">
<div class="container">
    <div class="header_inner">
        
        <div class="header_logo">
        <a href="https://h2o.ukavt.ru/"><img src="/images/logo.jpg" alt="Логотип УКАВТ" title="Логотип УКАВТ" class="logo_company"></a>
        </div> <!--/.header_logo-->
    <div class="tel_h">
        <div class="txt_phone"><p class="txt_help">ОТВЕТИМ НА ВСЕ ВОПРОСЫ:</p>
        </div><!--/.txt_phone-->
        <div class="phone_header">
         <div class="phone"><img src="/images/nav_1.png" class="img_phone"><a href="tel:+73517964277" class="phone_link">+7 (351) 700-75-17</a></div><!--/.phone-->
         <div class="phone"><img src="/images/nav_2.png" class="img_phone"><a href="mailto:sale@ukavt.ru" class="email">sale@ukavt.ru</a></div><!--/.email-->
         <div class="phone"><img src="/images/nav_3.png" class="img_phone"><p class="time">ПН-ПТ С 9:00 ДО 17:00</p></div><!--/.email-->
         </div>
    </div> <!--/.tel_h-->
            <nav class="nav">
                <a class="nav_link" href="https://h2o.ukavt.ru/about">О компании</a>
                <a class="nav_link" href="https://h2o.ukavt.ru/avtomatizaciya_kns">Автоматизация КНС</a>
                <a class="nav_link" href="https://h2o.ukavt.ru/nasosnye_stancii">Насосные станции</a>
                <a class="nav_link" href="https://h2o.ukavt.ru/contacts">Контакты</a>
            </nav> 
        
    </div>  <!--/.header_inner-->  
</div><!--/.container-->
</header>

<div class="container">
<div class="company_h1_h1">
               <h1>О компании</h1>
 </div><!--/.company_h1_h1--> 
 <div class="line">
  </div><!--/.line-->
</div>

<div class="kompani">
  <div class="container">
        
       <div class="komp_inner">
            <div class="number">
             <div class="numbers_tree">
                <img src="/images/number_1.jpg" title="Опыт работы" alt="Опыт работы" class="number_img">
                <p class="text_kompani">лет</p>
            </div>
            <div class="numbers_tree">
                <img src="/images/number_2.jpg" title="Реализованные проекты" alt="Реализованные проекты" class="number_img">
                <p class="text_kompani">готовых проектов</p>
            </div>
            <div class="numbers_tree">
                <img src="/images/number_3.jpg" title="Квалифицированный персонал" alt="Квалифицированный персонал" class="number_img">
                <p class="text_kompani">специалистов</p>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="txt_komp">
<p class="txt_komp_txt">ООО ИТЦ «УКАВТ» - это команда профессионалов, многопрофильный инженерно – технический центр с многолетним опытом работы на рынке автоматизации технологических процессов. За годы деятельности компании удалось успешно реализовать большое количество проектов по комплексной автоматизации и диспетчеризации, а также
сформировать сильную команду профессионалов, ответственно выполняющих свою работу.</p>
<p class="txt_komp_text">Специалисты нашей компании разрабатывают комплексные решения с использованием надежного оборудования по отличному соотношению цена/качество, от ведущих фирм-производителей.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        
  </div>  
</div>

<div class="certificat">
<div class="container">
<div class="company_h1_h1">
               <h1>Дилерские сертификаты</h1>
 </div><!--/.company_h1_h1--> 
 <div class="line">
  </div><!--/.line-->
<div class="company_h1_h1">
<p class="txt">Наша компания активно работает над развитием своей партнерской сети. На сегодняшний день, нашими партнерами в области поставок КИПиА являются такие компании как Овен, General Electric, Bosch Rexroth, BD Sensors и другие. Многолетнее успешное сотрудничество — наилучшая рекомендация для наших будущих Партнеров и Клиентов. Все необходимое оборудование от наших стратегических партнеров, вы сможете приобрести на нашем официальном сайте:
<div class="button_classa_ab">
    <a href="https://shop.ukavt.ru/" class="button_ab">Перейти на сайт</a>   
</div><!--/.button_classa_ab-->
</div><!--/.company_h1_h1-->
</div><!--/.container-->



<div class="certificates">
    <div class="container">
 
        <div class="img_for_certificates">
            
            <div class="dealer_certificate">
            <a id="single_1" href="https://picpig.ru/images/2019/12/05/certificate_1.jpg" height="213" title="Сертификат дилера КПСР"> <img width="400" alt="Сертификат дилера КПСР" src="https://picpig.ru/images/2019/12/05/certificate_1.jpg" class="img_certifi" height="270" title="Сертификат дилера КПСР" ИТЦ="null"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="dealer_certificate">
            <a id="single_2" href="/images/certificate_1.jpg" height="213" title="Сертификат дилера PIEZUS"> <img width="400" alt="Сертификат дилера PIEZUS" src="/images/certificate_1.jpg" class="img_certifi" height="270" title="Сертификат дилера PIEZUS" ИТЦ="null"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="dealer_certificate">
            <a id="single_3" href="/images/certificate_2.jpg" height="213" title="Сертификат дилера Тесей"> <img width="400" alt="Сертификат дилера Тесей" src="/images/certificate_2.jpg" class="img_certifi" height="270" title="Сертификат дилера Тесей" ИТЦ="null"> </a>    
            </div>
            <div class="dealer_certificate">
            <a id="single_4" href="/images/certificate_3.jpg" height="213" title="Сертификат дилера Овен"> <img width="400" alt="Сертификат дилера Овен" src="/images/certificate_3.jpg" class="img_certifi" height="270" title="Сертификат дилера Овен" ИТЦ="null"> </a>
            </div>
            <div class="dealer_certificate">
            <a id="single_5" href="/images/certificate_4.jpg" height="213" title="Сертификат дилера BD Sensors"> <img width="400" alt="Сертификат дилера BD Sensors" src="/images/certificate_4.jpg" class="img_certifi" height="270" title="Сертификат дилера BD Sensors" ИТЦ="null"> </a>
             </div>
            <div class="dealer_certificate">
            <a id="single_6" href="/images/certificate_6.jpg" height="213" title="Сертификат дилера GE"> <img width="400" alt="Сертификат дилера GE" src="/images/certificate_6.jpg" class="img_certifi1" height="270" title="Сертификат дилера GE" ИТЦ="null"> </a>    
            </div>
            <div class="dealer_certificate">
            <a id="single_7" href="/images/certificate_7.jpg" height="213" title="Сертификат дилера Прома"> <img width="400" alt="Сертификат дилера Прома" src="/images/certificate_7.jpg" class="img_certifi1" height="270" title="Сертификат дилера Прома" ИТЦ="null"> </a>
            </div>
            
        </div><!--/.img_for_certificates-->
    
    </div><!--/.container-->
</div><!--/.certificates-->
</div><!--/.certificat-->

<div class="container">
<div class="company_h1_h1">
               <h1>Фотографии производства</h1>
 </div><!--/.company_h1_h1--> 
 <div class="line">
  </div><!--/.line-->
</div>

<div class="production">
 <div class="container">
     
     <div class="img_for_product">
         <div class="img_product">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/0MyHMJ3/IMG-7404-min.jpg" title="Фото производства ИТЦ УКАВТ" alt="Фото производства ИТЦ УКАВТ" class="img_pro">  
         </div>
         <div class="img_product">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/hC0Rb3c/IMG-7408-min.jpg" title="Фото производства ИТЦ УКАВТ" alt="Фото производства ИТЦ УКАВТ" class="img_pro">  
         </div>
         <div class="img_product">
          <img src="https://i.ibb.co/Lg2hWyv/IMG-7402-min.jpg" title="Фото производства ИТЦ УКАВТ" alt="Фото производства ИТЦ УКАВТ" class="img_pro">  
         </div>
     </div>
 
 </div>
</div>



<footer class="footer">
<div class="container">
<div class="footer_inner">
    <div class="footer_container">
    <div class="footer_logo">
    <a href="#"><img src="/images/footer_logo.png" alt="Логотип УКАВТ" title="Логотип УКАВТ" class="logo_img"></a>
        <div class="footer_contact">
            
            <div class="phone_icons">
                <img src="/images/icons_footer_1.png" alt="geo" title="geo" class="geo"> 
                <div class="phone_txt">Адрес
                <div class="phone_txt_inner">
                <p class="phone_txt_inner_text">г. Челябинск, Комсомольский пр. д. 2 офис 603</p>
            </div><!--/.phone_txt_inner-->
        </div><!--/.phone_txt-->
            </div><!--/.phone_icons-->
             
        
            <div class="phone_icons">
        <img src="/images/icons_footer_2.png" alt="e-mail" title="e-mail" class="geo"> 
        <div class="phone_txt">E-mail
            <div class="phone_txt_inner">
            <p class="phone_txt_inner_text">sale@ukavt.ru</p>
            </div><!--/.phone_txt_inner-->
        </div><!--/.phone_txt-->
        </div><!--/.phone_icons-->
            
            <div class="phone_icons">
        <img src="/images/icons_footer_3.png" alt="phone" title="phone" class="geo">  
        <div class="phone_txt">Телефон
            <div class="phone_txt_inner">
            <p class="phone_txt_inner_text">+7 (351) 700 75 17</p>
            </div><!--/.phone_txt_inner-->
        </div><!--/.phone_txt-->
        </div><!--/.phone_icons-->  
        
        <div class="phone_icons">
            <div class="phone_txt_inner">
            <p class="phone_txt_inner_text_one">Все права защищены, ООО "ИТЦ УКАВТ"<br>
            ИНН/КПП 7448122124/744801001<br>
            ОГРН № 1097448007216</p>
            </div><!--/.phone_txt_inner-->
        </div><!--/.phone_icons-->  
            
       </div><!--/.footer_contact-->        
    </div><!--/.footer_logo-->
    </div><!--/.footer_container-->
    </div><!--/.footer_inner-->
</div><!--/.container-->
</footer> 
<!-- jQuery -->
<script
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Kastomnie Skripti -->
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>
        </body>
</html>
```

В консоле выдает ошибки:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at about:81

Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8='. The resource has been blocked.

Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at script.js:1
```

jQuery меняла неоднократно.

Comment: а где подключены библиотеки jquery, fancybox?

Comment: Вы ж не подключили jQuery :) Потому и Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: Я неверное старый код скопировала. Перед закрывающим body вставляла <!-- jQuery -->
<script
  src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- Kastomnie Skripti -->
<script src="/js/script.js"></script>

Comment: вы должны вставить свой скрипт после jquery, а не перед

Comment: Я думала сам скрипт будет лежать в файле script.js

Answer (score 2):

Нужно скачать, сохранить вместе с сайтом (внешние ссылки - плохая идея) и подключить JQuery (файл jquery.min.js ) и [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/howto)

По аналогии как вы делали с `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>`
Там же кладёте JQuery и подключаете точно так же.

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: К сожалению не помогло. Модалка все равно не работает. Сам код от Javascript почему то черный (jquery нормальный) + ошибки исчезли

Comment: Сейчас выдает желтую полоску с надписью: Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: "https://h2o.ukavt.ru/404.html".

Comment: Это потому что вы также и стили не подключили. Стили лучше оформить в отдельный файл .css и подключить.

Comment: А, сори, вижу что подключили стили. Ну фиг тогда знает.

Comment: Обычный стандартный код на подобии  document.write("У Вас включён JavaScript!"); почему то работает на сайте, но мой код для модального окна нет. Хотя он работает на другом сайте.

Comment: какой код не работает?

Comment: который самый верхний. Я его похоже не туда вставляю или как. Но код верный, он работает на другом сайте спокойно. На этом, не в какую

Comment: воспользуйтесь лучше программой удаленный помощник

Comment: Всем огромное спасибо! Я подключила fancybox и модальное окно заработало!